# Correct form for Past Progressive(?) of Arrive using Have

Tags: grammaticality, american-english

I am a software engineer writing comments about the behavior of a certain section of code.  While doing this, I found myself wanting to express an idea that I couldn't figure out how word in a sensical manner.

The sentence in question is as follows, and concerns the use of Past Progressive **arrive** using **has been**:

> This is an event that happens when a device is detected as ***having been arrived*** (e.g. plugged in)

I know the approach above is grammatically incorrect.  A few other attempts are:

> [A]... is detected as having recently arrived ...

> [B]... is detected as arrived ...

> [C]... is detected that is in the "arrived" state ...

[A] is my favorite option so far but something about the wording still feels off, like it needs a **been** before **arrived**. [B] appears to grammatically incorrect, though it is more succinct. [C], while grammatically correct, seems unnecessarily verbose and "robotic".

Note:  Due to external requirements, the usage of the word "arrive" is necessary

**What is the correct way to word that something *is just recently present*, using the word "arrived"?**

Edit 1:  As an example, the syntax I am attempting to emulate is as follows:

> This is an event that happens when a device is detected as ***having been removed*** (e.g. unplugged)

Edit 2:  Rewording the statement, rather than keeping the sentence structure in my example, is certainly acceptable.  The main requirement is the usage of ***arrive***.

Edit 2.1: Correcting the "which" vs "that" grammar error present in the initial example and initial question as pointed out by @tinfoil hat

Comment: This is probably "...is detected as having arrived". That is, it is now present when previously it wasn't; it has arrived. *Arrive* isn't conjugated with *be* these days: "I am arrived" is distinctly archaic.

Comment: Interesting.  It sounds, to me, like there is something.... "missing" with that wording (hence the addition of "recently" in [A]).  Though that feeling may just be because I am unused to using "arrived" in this context.

Comment: The issue with *having arrived* and *having been removed* is that *remove* is transitive and can form the passive, and *arrive* is intransitive and cannot.

Comment: Unfortunately the example you're trying to follow establishes a pretty ungainly pattern.  If you could rephrase as something like: "This is an event which happens when the removal of a devise is detected" or "This is an event which happens when X detects that a devise has been removed" you'd be in a better position.  "Is detected as having been removed" is already unnatural.

Comment: @Juhasz That is actually a great alternative.  Your suggested wording is certainly within my external requirements....

Comment: Correct: *This is an event **that** happens when a device is detected as having arrived.* The difference in *having arrived* and *having been removed* is the former is active voice and the latter is passive. In the first case, the device does the verb *arrive*. In the second, someone does the verb *remove* to the device. The only way to make them parallel is to change the wording (which you indicated you couldn't do).

Comment: @TinfoilHat I have updated the question to make the requirements more clear

Comment: *This event occurs when device arrival is detected. / This event occurs when device removal is detected.* There's still a mismatch of implied agency there, though. Maybe: *This event occurs when device arrival is detected. / This event occurs when device departure is detected.*

Comment: I appreciate the options.  The mismatched agency is acceptable, as the terms I am working with (Remove and Arrive) are inherently mismatched.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like that you must use "arrive" for your example.

If you must use 'arrive', I would say: This is an event that happens if detection be arrived at the device.

I used the verb be as a subjunctive mood(the present subjunctive).

Comment: I appreciate the answer.  However, your solution appears to introduce more grammatical errors than it solves, so I cannot accept it as correct.

Comment: Hmm. You can describe what is grammatically wrong? (actually arrive is an intransitive verb which can't be used as be+pp GRAMATICALLY.) But in real world it is used by news makers sometimes to make some effect. Furthermore, you must USE "ARRIVE"

Comment: While you appear to have a good grasp on the technicalities of English, you seem to lack in execution.  You have the right idea, technically, on how to rework my example.  However, everything after "if", in your answer, has all the hallmarks of a non-native english speaker.  Using "be" instead of "is".  "Arrived" is intransitive and cannot receive the action from a verb.  "detection ... at the device" is nonsensical in this context.

Comment: However, I am by no means an expert on the English language... which is why I posted the question in the first place.  Regardless of the technical correctness of your answer, in my case your answer obscures the meaning I am wanting to convey and I am better off using any of my initial suggestions, at least for my intended audience.